# jQuery+Regex: Need help in creating regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a website that I'd like to remove some content using jQuery.

I'd like to find anything in my content with this opening symbol [ and closing symbol ] and delete them both including the content in between them.

To be clear, this is actually a Shortcode format from WordPress. And some examples of them include

- [cudazi_column width='6' class='alpha' ]
- [cudazi_column_end]
- [cudazi_column width='6' class='omega' ]
- [cudazi_slider slide_delay="4000" slide_effect="slide" categories="home" ]

I want to be able to remove these from the content using jQuery

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have used this script in the past for another project and was wondering if I could use it again if I managed to get the right regex

```
$(".content").html(function(i,o){
  return o.replace( /@[0-9:\s]+(am|pm)/ig, '' );
});
```

Comment: [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: That post only applies if you're actually trying to parse complex content in a meaningful way. It does now apply to removing a limited number of syntactically similar tokens such as these.

Comment: I see. Therefore what I'd like to achieve isn't possible?

Comment: It is possible but there is a lot of room for error. For example if you include an intentional reference wrapped in those characters such as "The pony he comes [1]", it will also be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [ ] get used to for character ranges in regex (eg: [a-z] for all lower case characters) 
you need to quote them like:

```
\[
```

Both for the opening and closing square brackets:

```
\[ \]
```

In between them you want to match everything that is NOT a closing angle bracket:

```
[^\]]*
```

- means one or multiple times. If you would want to keep [] you would use + instead of *

So the later middle part between the start / finish matches you end up with:

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

and of course you'll need / around them:

```
/\[[^\]]*\]/
```

and you end up with:

```
$(".content").html(function(i,o){
  return o.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]//ig, '' );
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this and also a step-by-step explanation. I hope I can write simple regex myself in the future so thanks for this really cool explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The regex to match the string(s) in your description above would be:

```
/(\[.+\])/
```

So yes, you could do this:

```
$(".content").html(function(i,o){
  return o.replace( /(\[.+\])/g, '' );
});
```